# Layering images Love2d

Tags: image, graphics, love2d

I want to be able to layer images(PNG) with blank space over other images and have the images underneath still partly visible. right now my Image loading function will prints black space where it should have the background image.

Comment: Can you provide example images? LÖVE supports images with an alpha channel natively, but if your images don’t have that then you’ll have to do something more complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Noah mentioned, if your PNG images don't have an alpha channel, you can use LÖVE's blend modes.

https://love2d.org/wiki/BlendMode

Try displaying your image with "premultiplied", for instance.

```
love.graphics.setBlendMode("premultiplied")
love.graphics.draw(myImage)
love.graphics.setBlendMode("alpha")
```

"alpha" being the default blend mode.